# Primitive roots: If $p$ is a prime such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and $a$ is a primitive root, then $-a$ is also a primitive root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Primitive roots: If $p$ is a prime such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and $a$ is a primitive root, then $-a$ is also a primitive root.

In this particular question I did show that in fact $(-a)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, what is trivial. But, how can I assure that $p-1$ is its order?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean : If $a$ is a primitive root,$-a$ is one as well.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in the Question. Apart from the omission of an assumption about $a$ being "a primitive root", as Peter noted, it seems unlikely that being a primitive root *mod 4* is the real issue.

Comment: The edit to the title is helpful, but the same change in the body is more important.  Also, please spell out in the body that $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $a$ has order $p-1$ modulo $p$, and want to show that $-a$ also has order $p-1$. Suppose to the contrary that $(-a)^n\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for some $n\lt p-1$. Then $(-a)^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, so $a^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Since $a$ is a primitive root of $p$, it follows that $n=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

We show that this is impossible. Recall that since $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, there is an $x$ such that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Then 
$$1\equiv (-a)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv(x^2a)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv a^{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p},$$
contradicting the fact that $a$ has order $p-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume, $p-1$ is the order of $a$ modulo $p$ and assume $(-a)^m \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for some $m<p-1$. Then $m$ must be odd because otherwise we would have
$a^m\equiv 1 \pmod p$, which is impossible.

For such an odd $m$, we have $a^m\equiv -1\pmod p$ and therefore
$a^{2m}\equiv 1\pmod p$. But $2m=p-1$ is impossible because $p-1$ is divisible
by $4$. So, we have a contradiction again.

Comment: You should note it could be $p-1 \mid 2m$.

Answer (score -1):

If $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, it means that $p-1\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Therefore
$(-a)^{p-1}\equiv (-a)^{0} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

I would do it in this way.

Comment: Aren't you just repeating what the OP says already in the body of the Question?

Comment: I'm afraid, I can have misunderstood the question.